# How does an Unhallow with Deeper Darkness work?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, targeting

Unhallow says in part, emphasis mine:

> you may choose to fix a single spell effect to the unhallowed site. The spell effect lasts for 1 year and functions throughout the entire site, regardless of its normal duration and area or effect. **You may designate whether the effect applies to all creatures, creatures that share your faith or alignment, or creatures that adhere to another faith or alignment.** At the end of the year, the chosen effect lapses, but it can be renewed or replaced simply by casting unhallow again.
> Spell effects that may be tied to an unhallowed site include aid, bane, bless, cause fear, darkness, daylight, death ward, deeper darkness, detect magic, detect good, dimensional anchor, discern lies, dispel magic, endure elements, freedom of movement, invisibility purge, protection from energy, remove fear, resist energy, silence, tongues, and zone of truth.

What does the bolded section mean in the context of Deeper Darkness? If I choose to exclude e. g. Evil creatures, can they see through the darkness, since RAW the effect does not apply to them?  Additionally, most of the other effects on the list (e. g. Bless/Bane) target creatures, whereas Deeper Darkness targets objects, so what is the object? The point listed as the target for the Unhallow?

> Unhallow: Range touch, Area 40-ft. radius emanating from the touched point

Edit: Upon reflection, it seems like Silence would have a similar issue, since it's also an area that's centered on an object.

Comment: What do you mean by "The unhallowed point?" Do you mean the point from where the aura is emanating — or something else, say whether that point of origin would be considered an object? Also, welcome to rpg.se. While you are here, please take the [tour].

Comment: (I hope I am reading this UI right)
Sorry for not being more clear. Unhallow's effect is centered on a point that's chosen as the origin. 
> EFFECT
> Range touch
> Area 40-ft. radius emanating from the touched point
So maybe the DD emanates from that origin point.

Comment: No worries, I think that makes your question clearer, you are likely to receive an answer soon :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Deeper Darkness](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/deeper-darkness/)* causes the object touched to "radiate darkness in a 60-foot radius and the light level is lowered by two steps. ... This functions like darkness, but even creatures with darkvision cannot see within the spell’s confines."

That is, for all creatures within a 60-foot radius of the thing that's emanating the darkness, the ambient lighting conditions don't matter: it's magically dark, so much so that darkvision doesn't work.

However, *Unhallow* says that you "may designate whether the effect applies to all creatures, creatures that share your faith or alignment, or creatures that adhere to another faith or alignment." Let's take it as read that you can choose to exclude evil creatures from the effect (I think it means that you can either include "everybody", "followers of Sarenrae", "NG creatures", "those who do not follow Sarenrae", and "creatures who are not NG", but that's a different question), and that you do so. What happens?

*Unhallow* specifies that the effect can apply to only some creatures and not others. We've decided that it doesn't apply to evil creatures. Thus, from the perspective of an evil creature, there is no magical *Darkness* - ambient lighting conditions apply, and darkvision works normally (assuming it normally would; that is, that there isn't some other, confounding effect in play). It's only the non-evil creatures for whom the *Darkness* is in effect, so it's only they that can't see.

If the *Unhallow* effect is centered on an [Ioun Torch](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-torch/) (one of my favorite items) in a dark room:

1. the room is dark
2. the Ioun Torch creates normal illumination within 20 feet and shadowy illumination for another 20 feet
3. for evil creatures, stop here
4. non-evil creatures only: *Unhallow*'s *Deeper Darkness* lowers the light level by 2, so the normal illumination of the torch becomes darkness and the shadowy illumination becomes supernaturally dark
5. non-evil creatures only: *Unhallow*'s *Deeper Darkness* prevents darkvision from working